# Why are my pinch and rotate gestures not being recognized?

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to get familiar with each of the gestures IOS has to offer so I can implement them into my project. I have the tap and long press working just fine, but for some reason my pinch and rotate will not show up. I have tried a few other things like adding a delegate, and comparing it to others code, and I can't see anything wrong. The first part of code is my view did load and the rest are each of the methods for the gestures.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    int sw = self.view.frame.size.width;
    _tapped = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sw/2-90, 30, 300, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:_tapped];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReconginzed:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:5];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];//adds the gesture to the view

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressReconginzed:)];
    //[longPress numberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [longPress setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:3];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];


    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotate = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateReconginzed:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotate];


    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchReconginzed:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
}
```

Here are my methods for each gesture, my tap and long press work just fine.

```
-(void)tapReconginzed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
     NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tapped at %f", [sender locationInView:self.view].x]; 
     [_tapped setText:output];
}

-(void)longPressReconginzed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
     NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long pressed at %f", [sender locationInView:self.view].x];
     [_tapped setText:output];
}

-(void)rotateReconginzed:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender{
     if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
          CGPoint locationOne = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
          NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotated at %f and %f", locationOne.x, locationOne.y];
          [_tapped setText:output];
     }
}

-(void)pinchReconginzed:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender{
     if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
          CGPoint locationOne = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
          NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pinched pressed at %f and %f", locationOne.x, locationOne.y];
          [_tapped setText:output];
     }

     if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
         CGPoint locationOne = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
         NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pinched ended at %f and %f",locationOne.x, locationOne.y];
         [_tapped setText:output];
     }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if you might needs some calls to `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` so the gestures don't interfere with each other. You can test by commenting out all but one addGestureRecognizer call and seeing whether any single one is working in isolation.

Comment: I did try that and for some reason the pinch nor the rotate don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they not recognizing, or just not showing up in the label? You have multiple gesture recognizers trying to set the text in the same label, so you may just not be seeing all the updates. Try using `NSLog` to see whether the gestures are actually being recognized.

If they aren’t, you may also want to try setting the pinch and rotate gestures’ `delegate`s to `self`, and then returning `YES` from `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`.

**Update:** to eliminate the possibility of conflicts, try commenting out all but the pinch, or all but the rotate, and see if they work on their own. If not, you may have something configured wrong. Get them working individually before trying to get them working together.

Comment: I will try this now, and let you know thank you for your time. Because i'm not sure if the gesture is working at all or now. Overall the code looks right?

Comment: Nothing is coming up on the NSLog, any tips?

Comment: Did you try the second part? Make sure you set the delegates, or that method won’t be called.

Comment: Added another suggestion to my answer.